# Two function as val declaration give two different result

Tags: scala

I have two function declared as val

```
val add2: (Int, Int) => Int = (x,y) => {
  println("add2 called")
  x + y
}

val add3: (Int, Int) => Int = {
  println("add2 called")
  _ + _
}
```

when I try run them I get two different results

```
add2(1,2)
add2 called
res7: Int = 3
```

and

```
add3(1,2)
res8: Int = 3
```

I don't understand why this two functions give different results.

Maybe I mis-expressed myself. In the first case there is a side effect in the second there is not. But I receive two variables with different functions

Comment: are you sure its a the provide different result?

Comment: The results are identical?

Comment: In first case i have printed string in second not

Comment: could you please verify your results??

Comment: Maybe I mis-expressed myself. In the first case there is a side effect in the second there is no. But i receive two variables with different functions. It's the most important

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first syntax `val add2: (Int, Int) => Int = (x,y) => ...` is declaring a function whose body is:

```
println("add2 called")
x + y
```

i.e. *every* time the function is called the `println` is executed followed by returning the value of `x + y`

The second syntax is declaring an anonymous function as the result/value of the block of code:

```
{
  println("add2 called")
  _ + _
}
```

The value of the block of code is just the last line: `_ + _` and the `println` is executed *only once* at the time when `add3` is being assigned.

Think of the second example in the same way as this snippet assigns the value 42 to `x`:

```
val x = {
    println("Calculating")
    val a = 21
    val b = 21
    a + b
}
```

---

**Clarification:**

Both syntaxes have this part in common: `val add: (Int, Int) => Int = ...` i.e. the type declaration "this is going to be a function that takes two Ints and returns an Int" so let's look at the bit that's different:

The First one assigns `... = (x,y) => { ... }` i.e. assigns a function declared using the `=>` operator.

The second example assigns the value of a block `... = { ... }` where the value of the block (its last line) is an anonymous function making use of [one Scala's uses for underscores](http://ananthakumaran.in/2010/03/29/scala-underscore-magic.html).

Comment: Not clear here. How compiler decides that in first case he have full function body  but in second case he must return only result. Only by anonymous declaration?

Comment: I've had a stab at adding some clarification. Let me know if that helps at all!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Question closed.